# VB.NET Error While inserting data to microsoft access

Tags: .net, vb.net, ms-access, .net-4.0

Just a simple thing that i wanna do.., i want to insert the data to database  ., and complete., but there when run they said , **Syntax error in INSERT INTO statement.**  i think thats no error anymore..

advice?

```
Dim cmdinsrtuser As OleDbCommand = New OleDbCommand("Insert into TblPassword (Username,password,PWDMaintenance,awb,Acc_no) Values (@txtUsername,@txtpassword,@chckadmin,@chckawb,'ADMIN')", con)

                cmdinsrtuser.Parameters.AddWithValue("@txtpassword", txtPassword.Text)
                cmdinsrtuser.Parameters.AddWithValue("@txtUsername", txtUsername.Text)
                If Check9.Checked = True Then
                    cmdinsrtuser.Parameters.AddWithValue("@chckadmin", 1)
                Else
                    cmdinsrtuser.Parameters.AddWithValue("@chckadmin", 0)
                End If

                If cawb.Checked = True Then
                    cmdinsrtuser.Parameters.AddWithValue("@chckawb", 1)
                Else
                    cmdinsrtuser.Parameters.AddWithValue("@chckawb", 0)
                End If

                cmdinsrtuser.ExecuteNonQuery()
```

this is the error dialogg..

[image]

Comment: Password is a reserved word in access - you need to escape it with square brackets.  you should never ever store passwords as plaintext - hash them

Comment: owh like that.., thank you, its work.., i just test the password .. i dont know how to hash

can you show me a little how to hash

Comment: Use MD5, SHA1 or similar hashing algorithm to store hashed values into DB, and place hashing code right after user submitting login form.